# Getting error -> Invalid header field name, with 32

Tags: java, api, flutter

I am new to Flutter, I am making an API call. Request is going on my server, but I am getting this error (Invalid header field name, with 32) in Flutter logs and no any response. I have tried to read a simple JSON file from my server url, like http://example.com/test.json, but getting the same error. Also, I want to know if Flutter has any limitations on API calls from static IP, if my web application is not yet hosted on any domain?

Comment: @roottraveller No, I have tried this solution, but no luck :-(

Comment: Can you add your error log? Also have you tried to debug the application?

Comment: V/BoostFramework(26710): BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@596bdcb
I/art     (26710): Do partial code cache collection, code=26KB, data=29KB
I/art     (26710): After code cache collection, code=26KB, data=29KB
I/art     (26710): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/flutter (26710): Invalid header field name, with 32
I/flutter (26710): Invalid header field name, with 32

Comment: @Akin I tried to debug the application. "C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\http-0.12.2\lib\src\io_client.dart" has a method Future<IOStreamedResponse> send(BaseRequest request) async {} which is throwing the exception "ClientException (Invalid header field name, with 32)".